# Why php print_r($array) will not print the spaces in a string

Tags: php, string, strlen

```
$myArray = array();

array_push($myArray, "'     a'");

use Framework\ArrayMethods as ArrayMethods;
print_r(($myArray));
print_r(ArrayMethods::lengtOfElements($myArray));
```

The output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => ' a' ) Array ( [0] => 8 )
```

So there is only one whitespace before a in the printed string, but the strelen returns 8?
How to make it print '     a' ?

Comment: View your page source, not what you see in the browser.

Comment: But how to see it the browser?

Comment: Why downvotes I do not understand? Downvoters can you please explain why?

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr); echo '</pre>'`. you're getting downvoted because this is a basic browser thing - multiple spaces are NOT printed when a browser is rendering html.

Comment: Voted to reopen because some of us here on Stack have to use mod privileges competently and responsibly.

Comment: This question is 4 years, 9 months old why did you voted it to open it today? @John

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to view in your browser wrap this:

```
print_r(($myArray));
print_r(ArrayMethods::lengtOfElements($myArray));
```

So it has `<pre>` tags:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(($myArray));
print_r(ArrayMethods::lengtOfElements($myArray));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Marc-B commented, the browser is collapsing multiple consecutive spaces into a single space. The solutions to this are:

1. Wrap the text in `<pre></pre>` tags.
2. Use the CSS [`white-space` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).
3. Replace the spaces with the HTML `&nbsp;` entity. [non-breaking space]

eg:

```
preg_replace("/ /", "&nbsp;", "     a");
//output: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;a
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because multiple spaces (two or more in a row) in html will only display as a single space. if you 'view source' you may see a different result.

You can use pre tags to get round this if you want to see in the actual browser rather than the source:

```
$myArray = array();

array_push($myArray, "'     a'");

echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: @JakeGould that is a print_r with pre tags either side? My answer's like it is to illustrate the point that the `print_r` was outputting the spaces